# Compiling a library with Rcpp causing many 'unknown type'/'no member named' errors

Tags: r, compiler-errors, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to compile a package that includes Rcpp functions and compilation is finding a ton of errors:

```
 ==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source polowam
 
 * installing to library ‘/Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library’
 * installing *source* package ‘polowam’ ...
 ** using staged installation
 ** libs
 using C++ compiler: ‘clang version 14.0.6’
 clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++17 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
 using SDK: ‘’
 In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:316:
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:150:34: error: unknown type name 'ldiv_t'
 inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ldiv_t div(long __x, long __y) _NOEXCEPT {
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:151:12: error: no member named 'ldiv' in the global namespace
 return ::ldiv(__x, __y);
 ~~^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:154:34: error: unknown type name 'lldiv_t'
 inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY lldiv_t div(long long __x,
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:156:12: error: no member named 'lldiv' in the global namespace
 return ::lldiv(__x, __y);
 ~~^
 In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:388:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_NAN'
 return __builtin_fpclassify(FP_NAN, FP_INFINITE, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO, __x);
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:388:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_INFINITE'
 return __builtin_fpclassify(FP_NAN, FP_INFINITE, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO, __x);
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:388:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_NORMAL'
 return __builtin_fpclassify(FP_NAN, FP_INFINITE, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO, __x);
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:388:63: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_SUBNORMAL'
 return __builtin_fpclassify(FP_NAN, FP_INFINITE, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO, __x);
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:388:77: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_ZERO'
 return __builtin_fpclassify(FP_NAN, FP_INFINITE, FP_NORMAL, FP_SUBNORMAL, FP_ZERO, __x);
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:393:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_ZERO'
 return __x == 0 ? FP_ZERO : FP_NORMAL;
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:393:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FP_NORMAL'
 return __x == 0 ? FP_ZERO : FP_NORMAL;
 ^
 In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:523:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__hash_table:19:
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:43:12: error: reference to unresolved using declaration
 _VSTD::memcpy(&__r, __p, sizeof(__r));
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:80:1: note: using declaration annotated with 'using_if_exists' here
 using ::memcpy _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
 ^
 In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:523:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__hash_table:22:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:14:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/construct_at.h:23:
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/new:355:14: error: no member named 'aligned_alloc' in the global namespace
 return ::aligned_alloc(__alignment, __size > __rounded_size ? __size : __rounded_size);
 ~~^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/new:369:5: error: no type named 'free' in the global namespace
 ::free(__ptr);
 ~~^
 In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_map:528:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:23:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdexcept:48:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:100:
 In file included from /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mbstate_t.h:29:
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:143:77: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcschr'
 wchar_t* __libcpp_wcschr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return (wchar_t*)wcschr(__s, __c);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:150:87: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcspbrk'
 wchar_t* __libcpp_wcspbrk(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcspbrk(__s1, __s2);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:157:78: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcsrchr'; did you mean 'wcschr'?
 wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsrchr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return (wchar_t*)wcsrchr(__s, __c);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:145:16: note: 'wcschr' declared here
 const wchar_t* wcschr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:164:86: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcsstr'; did you mean 'wcschr'?
 wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsstr(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcsstr(__s1, __s2);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:147:16: note: 'wcschr' declared here
 wchar_t* wcschr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:164:86: error: no matching function for call to 'wcschr'
 wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsstr(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcsstr(__s1, __s2);}
 ^
 /Users/hkanari/anaconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:147:16: note: candidate disabled: <no message provided>
 wchar_t* wcschr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
 ^
 fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
 20 errors generated.
 make: *** [/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf:198: RcppExports.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘polowam’
 * removing ‘/Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/polowam’
 * restoring previous ‘/Users/hkanari/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/polowam’
 
 Exited with status 1.
```

These errors seem to be originating from standard C++ libraries/utilities, so I'm confused what is causing this.

I am on an M2 Mac mini with macOS Ventura 13.4.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

I have tried comparing my package to other packages that use Rcpp to try and find anything I'm missing to use Rcpp in my package, but have had no success finding anything new.

I also tried creating a skeleton R package with Rcpp using Rcpp.package.skeleton() and while it does get created, it is also unable to compile due to the same errors.

Outside of the context of the package I am able to use Rcpp (with Rcpp::cppfunction for example) without issue.

Comment: I don't work on macOS myself, but we are in good standing for it at CRAN _when the proper tools are used_. I see anaconda in your logs:  are you using the toolchain from https://mac.r-project.org/ ?  If not, I think you may be at a dead end as I do not think you can use anaconda compilers with standard R.  Similarly I don't think you can drop standard R into an anaconda setup.  In short, it looks as if you may help with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have downloaded and installed the gfortran-12.2-universal.pkg, but how do I get RStudio to use this compiler instead of anaconda?

Comment: As I said, I am not a macOS user. My best suggestion is that you post on the r-sig-mac list. We have some pointers in the [Rcpp FAQ](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/vignettes/pdf/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) (that I just updated) but those may be stale too as I work on Ubuntu,